# Understanding CMYK to RGB conversion code

Tags: imagemagick, imagick

I am looking at the top comment on this page:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecolorspace.php

It has sample code for converting a CMYK image to RGB. However, there are two things I do not understand:

1. It uses the `profileImage` function twice. Once to set the profile to CMYK if the image does not currently have a profile. The second use of the function adds the RGB profile to the image. Apparently, this means that the image now has at least two image profiles attached to it.

**Question 1:**  Why would you want the image to have both a CMYK profile and an RGB profile? What exactly is being done here? How exactly does adding a second profile convert the image from CMYK to RGB?

2. The very last line in the code is using the `stripImage` function which removes the profiles completely along with other things such as EXIF data.

**Question 2:** Why are we removing the profiles? Doesn't that undo everything that we just did?

Answer (score 0):

If the input image is CMYK and does not have a profile, then you can convert it two ways. The first is to simply use -colorspace sRGB. But that is not so accurate. A better way is to use two profiles. The first defines the input colorspace as CMYK and gives it a precise definition of its gamut and the second specifies it wants to convert to sRGB. There are a number of CMYK type profiles that can be used. Without more knowledge, I prefer USWebCoatedSWOP.icc. Likewise there are several sRGB profiles. See http://www.color.org/srgbprofiles.xalter and https://github.com/ellelstone/elles_icc_profiles/tree/master/profiles for profiles.

Comment: So once it converts it to sRGB what is the purpose of having the original CMYK profile attached to it as well? Also, why is the code using the stripImage function?